# How do I show that the following operation is a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know I must show vector addition and scalar multiplication holds, but I am unsure as how to show it.
$$I: R[5,6] \rightarrow R[5,6]: I(f(x)) = \int_{5}^{x}f(t)dt, \textrm{ } 5\leq x\leq 6$$

Comment: Hint: Try to use the properties of integrals

Comment: Do you know what does a **linear transformation** mean ?

Comment: For a) I know I need to show that scalar multiplication and vector addition hold for the linear transformation to be true. I also recognize that the domain and the codomain are the same. I am just not sure how I should be writing it out. I have not tried b) yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be clear that

$ \int_{0}^{x}(af(t)+bg(t))dt= a\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt+b \int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt$.

This shows linearity.

For b) observe that $T(f)$ is the antiderivative of $f$ with $T(f)(0)=0$.